# Is there a way to create a popup form in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a level editor for my game, and I can't figure out how to create popup forms.

Here's an example of what I want from osu!:

[image: osu song setup screen]

It doesn't have to be exactly like this, it just has to pop out of the game.

I want the contents of the form to look something like this:

[image: width (form) height (form)]

Is this possible?

Comment: What platform(s) are you targeting? What have you already tried? How was the result different from your intentions?

Comment: @Ruzihm I am targeting Windows. I have not tried anything because I don't know where to look.

Comment: Must the "pop out" action really mean a separate window/dialog box from the game window?

Comment: Well you *could* build a separate application that is only your dialogue window and a callback once it is submitted and open it from and hook it up to your Unity app .. but that sounds not like the way you want to go here ;)

Comment: @Ruzihm Preferably, yes, I would like a dialogue box independent of the game window. Just like a Windows popup.

Comment: Actually the link is: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/native-file-browser-68064

Answer (score -2):

It's completely impossible to open a separate window, from Unity.

Comment: No, it isn't. Check this plugin: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/native-file-browser-68064

Comment: Good work - but wait - that's just a **file browser** right?    As I understand it quite different from opening a general popup window (for, say, preferences etc.)

Comment: I actually merged the WinForms once into Unity application (due to client requirement). It is possible - but as I cannot provide my code as proof, I showed you someone else's work :-)